# Windows does not shut down

Tags: windows, shutdown

I have shutdown problem in my desktop system.

I have a Core 2 Duo, 1 GB RAM, Windows XP SP2.

I suspect that the problem might be due to virus so I have updated the virus definitions (Microsoft Security Essentials), scanned my system completely. The issue was not resolved, so I installed Windows XP SP3 alone. Still I have same problem. Then, I installed Windows 7. But my shutdown problem not resolved.

Does the above problem occur due to hardware problem?

Note: My system has a CMOS checksum error: ["CMOS check sum error" while booting](https://superuser.com/questions/487857/cmos-check-sum-error-press-f1-to-continue)

Comment: What happens when you click on shutdown?

Comment: In Windows xp - a page loading with the message "windows shutting down" for long time.  In windows 7  - "shutting down" page is loading for a minute and blank screen displayed. but in both os, cpu power is not truned off. I am turn off my system by holding the cpu power button.

Comment: Did you resolve your [other question](http://superuser.com/q/487857/97028) about the checksum error? I believe this problem will likely be resolved when the other is fixed.

Comment: I have the check sum error for last 6 months. but shutdown problem occurred in two weeks before.

Comment: I'd also recomment checking the Power/ACPI Sleep settings in your BIOS. Those can prevent the final OFF signal from working properly. Of course, you will probably have to resolve your checksum problem first (try resetting BIOS to defaults, restarting a few times, setting BIOS clock properly, and, if that fails, buying a new BIOS battery) in order for settings to be reliably committed.

Comment: Hi Zac B, thanks for your suggestion. I will check and let you know. I have another doubt. Is there any possibilities to virus affect the BIOS settings? I have changed "first bootable device" to cdrom. it is automatically changed to floppy after 4 or 5 booting.

Comment: Your CMOS is corrupt you need to resolve that problem.

Answer (score 0):

which motherboard are you using? 
I have the same exact problem in windows vista/7/8 with some asus mainboards.

The problem was given by the option "allow windows to turn off this device" that wasn't flagged: everytime I shut down the pc, windows closes and then the monitor remained stuck on a black screen.

http://vip.asus.com/forum/view.aspx?board_id=1&model=P5B-E&id=20110201174534805&page=1&SLanguage=en-us

Comment: MainBoard -> Gigabyte 945GZM-S2 , Chipset -> Intel i945G/GZ , Processor -> Intel Core 2 Duo E4400 @ 2000 MHz , BIOS Version ->FC HI, BIOS Date ->04/24/2007(mm/dd/yyyy). OS: both xp and windows 7 have the same problem.